# Does C++ R-Value has a size?

Tags: c++

Let's assume the largest number an `int` variable can hold is `10`. Consider the following situation:

```cpp
main()
{
int r1 = 10;
int r2 = 1;

int x = r1 + r2;
}
```

According to my current little knowledge, `r1 + r2` expression creates a temporary variable to hold the result before copying that value to `x`.

What i want to know is since the largest `x` can hold is `10`, i know (it's a guess actually) that if i print `x`, i get `10`. But what about `r1 + r2` ?. Does this temporary variable that represent the result of `r1 + r2` expression also hold 10 ?.

In other words does this temporary variable also has a largest it can hold ?

This is probably a noob question and i apologise.

**Please Note:**

> I asked this question based on what i thought what overflowing is. That is; i thought when a variable reach to a state where (let's say for an integer case), if i add one more integer to it's value it's gonna overflow. And i thought when that happens the maximum value it holds gonna stay the same regardless of me increasing it. But that's not the case apparently. The behaviour is undefined when overflow for most types. **check @bolov's answer**

Comment: Temporary has type too. If it's `int`, then same as `x`. And in this case, it is `int`.

Comment: @JaMiT the OP doesn't know what overflow is, that's why he/she asks.

Comment: @songyuanyao Is it because x being int or the r1 and r2 are being int ? If i consider just the expression `r1+r2;` is it gonna make a temporary of type int as well ?

Comment: @C4se It's because `r1` and `r2` are `int`, then `r1+r2` returns `int`.

Comment: I actually asked this question not knowing but guessing what overflowing a variable means. I apologise.

Comment: @C4se Don't worry too much about it. Just try to be more precise in the future, and continue to accept that people will read what you write instead of what you meant to write. When writing a useful answer, it helps to know where the question is coming from.

Comment: @JaMiT i understand. I'll try to avoid this mistake next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Signed integers

Computing a value larger than the maximum value or smaller than the minimum value of an signed integer type is called "overflow" and is Undefined Behavior.

E.g.:

```
int a = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int b = 1;
a + b;
```

The above program has Undefined Behavior because the type of `a + b` is `int` and the value computed would overflow.

> § 8 Expressions [expr]
>
> § 8.1 Preamble [expr.pre]
>
> 4. If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>      its type, the behavior is undefined.

## Unsigned integers

Unsigned integers do not overflow because they are always computed in modulo arithmetic.

```
unsigned a = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max();
a + 1; // guaranteed to be 0

unsigned b = 0;
b - 1; // guaranteed to be std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max();
```

> §6.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]
>
> 4. Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n
>      is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular
>      size of integer <sup>49</sup>
>
> 49) This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a
>   result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
>   value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type.

Comment: I thought when the variable reach the overflowing state, it's gonna keep holding the maximum value it can hold regardless of the value we assign to it getting increased.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you cannot be sure, if it creates a new variable at all. I mean it all depends on the compiler, compiler options, etc. For instance, in some circumstances, the compiler can just calculate the value of the r-value (if it is vivid and possible for that point) and just put the calculated value into the variable.

For your example, it is obvious, that `r1 + r2 == 11`. Then the `x` might be constructed using a value `11`. And this also doesn't mean, that the `x` will 100% constructed and a constructor will be called for him.

Once I debugged and saw, that a variable I declared (and defined) was not created at all (and also some calculations I had). That was because I didn't use the variable in any meaningful way and set the optimization to the highest level.

Comment: So sometimes some compilers decides not to create temporary variables when it's possible ??  Did i get that right ?

Comment: @C4se he is talking about the [as-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) [rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)